# To prove two vectors are linearly independent or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-independence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iek2K.png)

Concerning the second question, I attempted to use an augmented matrix to test whether the linear system is consistent or not but failed. I also tried to turn to the original definition by writing mv+nAv=0.But I just cannot prove the coefficient must be zero. How should I complete the proof?

Comment: This isn't a test paper, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please upload the picture directly here.

Comment: Note $A$ is skew symmetric, so $Av$ and $v$ are orthogonal, and hence linearly independent since nonzero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$A\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\v_2 \\v_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cv_2-v_3 \\-cv_1+av_3 \\bv_1-av_2\end{bmatrix}$

$\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*, \exists (v_1,v_2,v_3)\neq (0,0,0)\begin{cases}cv_2-bv_3=\lambda v_1 \\ -cv_1+av_3 =\lambda v_2 \\  bv_1-av_2=\lambda v_3\end{cases} \iff \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*, \exists (v_1,v_2,v_3)\neq (0,0,0)\begin{cases}\lambda v_1 -cv_2+bv_3=0\\ -cv_1-\lambda v_2+av_3=0 \\  bv_1-av_2-\lambda v_3=0\end{cases} \iff \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*,\begin{vmatrix}\lambda &  -c& b \\-c & -\lambda & a \\b & -a & -\lambda
\end{vmatrix}= 0 \iff \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*,\lambda^3+(a^2+b^2+c^2)\lambda =0 \iff \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*,p(\lambda):=\lambda(\lambda^2+a^2+b^2+c^2)=0$

Now, $\forall \lambda \neq 0,p(\lambda)\neq 0$ since $(a,b,c)\neq (0,0,0)$.
So, $v$ and $Av$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you!!!!! 